# How to automatically match the length in rows of two Excel tables?

Tags: excel, match, rows

I have a worksheet with one Excel table. Time by time I may add or remove rows from that table. I created another table in another worksheet of the same workbook. I wish to automatically change the number of rows of that table to match the number of rows on the first table. That's because the first column of second table refers to the first column of first table, so the number of rows must be the same. So, if first table has 100 rows, second table must have 100 rows. If I add a row to first table, second table must have 101 rows. If I remove a row from first table, second table must have 99 rows. Is that possible without manually changing each time second table?

Comment: What is the difference between the 2 tables?

Comment: The two tables are different but they have in the first column the same values. Let us say, for example, that the first table is a list of names with personal data, whereas the second table is a list of the same names (since the first column gets values from the first column of the other table) but the other fields are reservation information.

Comment: In practice I need to "sync" two tables that shares the same first column, but have different data in the the others. Each time I add or remove a record from first table, the a record associated to the same first field has to be added or removed from second table.